# Add a button using CSS and CoffeeScript

Tags: css, coffeescript

I want to change "ADD YOURS" to a button.

the code for the text is here

```
addMorePhotosButton = $ """
  <div style="float:left;font-size:32px">
    <br>
    Everyone's photos from
    "<span class="jvreplacewitheventname">this event</span>"
    <a class="jvaddmorephotosbutton" href="#">+Add yours!</a>
    <br/>
  </div>
"""

addMorePhotosInfoDiv.append addMorePhotosButton
```

I added the CSS for the button itself to the proper CSS file, I just need to know what code to place above to get it to render correctly.

You can see the link where I want the button to appear, here:

http://www.albumpl.us/gallery/trial/photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use the `<button>` tag instead of `<a>`. I don't recommend this, as there are some annoying cross-browser inconsistencies with the visual look of `<button>`s.
2. (Recommended) Style the `<span`/`<a>` tags with your CSS to give them a button-like appearance. Do a Google search for "[css button](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+button)" to see some common approaches.

Comment: so I used that button maker before I posted here - http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/ I now have the code posted in my css file... i just need to know exactly how to frame it on the file itself to tell it that im using the button, and not the text... does that make sense?

Comment: @adam I'm really not sure what you're asking. The button looks fine now, except that the the link text is underlined. To fix that, add `a.jvaddmorephotosbutton {text-decoration: none;}` to your CSS.